# Memory issues with XML-based spring configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, pojo

I am creating a project for that I have tested both the XML-based spring configurations and Pure Java based configuration. My project is simple, it will listen on a RabbitMQ queue and perform an operation. Till now, I was not published anything in that queue. The code and requirement with both type of configurations are same. But, in case of XML-based configuration my memory uses are increases gradually and after sometime it will release all the increased memory. After that it again gradually increases.

The below JProfiler image that showing this scenario.

[image: JProfiler image]

Can someone explain why this happens? Is there something wrong with XML-based configuration?
Thanks for your efforts.

**edit 1**: Spring version -> 5.1.6.RELEASE (For annotation based) and 5.2.18.RELEASE (For XML based)

**edit 2**: Code I have used,

```
<beans ....>
     <bean id="output" class="com.test.Output" />
</beans>

public class XmlConfigTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/applicationContext.xml");
        Output output = (Output) ctx.getBean("output");
        output.performOperation();
    }
}


public class AnnotationConfigTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringContextGenerator.class);
        Output output = (Output) ctx.getBean("output");
        output.performOperation();
    }
}
```

I have used code like that where I get bean from XML and Annotations and perform a operations in it.

When it started:

[image: JProfile Image]

Just before GC collects all garbage object:

[image: JProfiler Image]

Comment: You have provided zero code, so we have zero idea what you're doing

Comment: @lance-java
I have added some code. I cannot share the exact code. I think you can understand this.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference as the XML is merely used to generate the BeanDefinition objects. Also, the jprofiler image itself doesn't really prove anything. If you have concerns, best is to take two heap dumps and check the difference between the two to gain insights.

Comment: For starters compare the same version of Spring. Also without knowing what is going on  in the `performOperation` this will be impossible to answer. Also I don't see any issue with the memory just regular java GC behavior.

Comment: You question says you have "issues" but it's not clear what the issues are. The Profiler graph looks perfectly normal: a gradual increase in heap usage until the grabage collector decides to kick in, then a reduction and another gradual increase. Why is this an "Issue"?

Comment: I agree with Michael Kay.  It is the garbage collection which normally only runs when needed in background.  What percentage of the memory is being used when you see the usage changing?

Comment: @jdweng, percentage of memory changing is about 25%.
At start, memory uses 23.44MB and just before GC memory uses will be 29.93MB.

Answer (score 0):

That is totally fine and normal java Garbage-Collection behavior ([as you can read here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)).

> In a programming language like C, allocating and deallocating memory is a manual process. In Java, process of deallocating memory is handled automatically by the garbage collector.

Also, 70 MB is no huge memory allocation nowadays.